# Save is broken and how to save as mp4?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I saved a project, opened it later (solely using video editor, just compiling videos) and it does nothing. It plays, but no sound or video, but when I enter something new into it then it works. Also, how do I save my video as mp4?

Comment: Most likely you moved your blend file or the video footage into another folder. So Blender can't find the files anymore.

Answer (score 2):

In the VSE window, select an item, press N, press the folder icon and relocate your missing file. Do the same for every missing file.

[image]

These are the settings for saving as mp4, with H264 codec.

[image]